# NameError: uninitialized constant Order::AASM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

I am implement a order system with AASM, but when I use `rails c` to check the function, but something wrong happen. `NameError: uninitialized constant Order::AASM`

[image: Bug showed in console]

There is `gem 'aasm'` in the Gemfile.
I have searched Google and StackOverflow with `NameError: uninitialized constant Order::AASM`, but got nothing that did work.

I have reload `bundle install` and `rails s`, even `reboot` the computer.
This is my code.

[image]

[order's gist is here.](https://gist.github.com/zhang-zedong/e29607af1283604efd1d513d38b97468)

How to fix this?
And if I can't find the right question, or you need more information, could you point it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Comment out `gem 'spring'`and `gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'`
2. Run `bundle install`

Or try upgrading spring in your project:

1. In your gemfile `gem 'spring', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.2'`
2. Run `bundle update spring`

Comment: Def seems like it's an issue with `spring`. I don't have `spring-watcher-listen` in my project but still have the issue. Commenting it out fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to include more code into your question - the whole `aasm` block.

Also, try specifying the model db column you are applying your AASM states to:

```
  aasm :column => 'state'
    state :active
    state :completed
    state :scheduled
```